# Converting from EPUB to PDF scrambles text. When I copy paste it, it turns up normal, but when viewing, it's a bunch of random characters

Tags: pdf, fonts, conversion, epub

I am exporting an ebook from epub to pdf, for view on my computer. I don't want to use it on an e reader, I just want a straight pdf.

As I export, it seems I can maintain page breaks, but the cover image gets mushed (squeezed from top to bottom).

Some segments of text that are in a different Font and Size scramble and display unrelated characters, but when I highlight the text and copy paste it, it is the original text.
For example:
[This reads the word "Contents" in the table of contents.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtZdz.png)

I assume this is an issue with my export settings.

Also, images will frequently clip into another blank page, and some pages show up blank.

EDIT: I am using Calibre as my method of conversion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Most likely the content is not licensed for export to PDF (and thence to anywhere).

Comment: It might be helpful to [edit] your question and add the software tools you are using.

Comment: I'm using Calibre extensively for that purpose and I never had such a problem. Would it be possible to post online an example epub with instructions of where does the problem occur? (Dropbox, OneDrive etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution. For some reason, Calibre was detecting the font of the EPUB to something strange, Avenir, I think, and when I went into a pdf and changed the font, everything was fine.
So, it replaced the font for those specific pieces of text.

Or something like that.

Comment: If you could [edit] your answer and describe the exact steps you used to solve this problem, it might be more helpful to others.